# NoReverseMatch at / after upgrade from 1.3 to 1.4

Tags: django, exception, django-urls

The project was working fine with Django 1.3, once I updated to 1.4 results on this error:

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found.

urls.py:

```
from views import home

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', home),
    (r'^projects/', include('projects.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

projects.url:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('projectcenter.projects.views',
    url(r'project/(\d+)/$', project_detail, name = 'project_detail' ),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import  RequestContext 
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from projects.models import Project

def home(request):

    template = 'index.html'
    user = request.user
    projects = Project.objects.current()
    if projects:
        map_center = projects[0].location 
    else:
        map_center = (0, 0)

    data = {'user': user,
            'projects': projects,
            'map_center': map_center ,
            }
    return render_to_response(template, data, 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: we'd need to see your projects.urls file?

Comment: Can you also post the full stack trace, please?

Comment: yes it's here: http://dpaste.com/789273/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the index.html template I was inheriting from this template:

{% extends "admin/change_list.html"%}

I removed the line above and it worked fine.

I really don't know why it worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today and solved it by just updating the relevant line to:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Not sure why that fixed it though.